# Alternative to Treeview in VBA excel 2016 64bit

Tags: excel, vba, treeview, 64-bit, excel-2016

I am trying to run an excel with VBA that has treeview control in it. It is working fine in 32bit machines but on 64bit machine with excel 2016 it is not working,with the error, treeview component is not found.

Is there any other similar component which I can replace treeview with?

Comment: You may find this question helpful for your problem. [Excel VBA “Automation Error” due to Jan 2016 Office Update, probably caused by MSCOMCTL.OCX (Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.o (Service Pack 6))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803843/excel-vba-automation-error-due-to-jan-2016-office-update-probably-caused-by-m)

Comment: I understand it is available in 2016 with name of treemap.Use F1 and give search term Treeview, related info is available in online help.

Comment: Suppose the treeview is a COM component. Have you tried to re-register the treeview component for 64-bit? More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873). Note On a 64-bit version of Windows operating system, there are two versions of the Regsv32.exe file:
The 64-bit version is %systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe.
The 32-bit version is %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe.

Comment: FYI Microsoft has not and never will release a 64-bit version of the Common Controls using COM.  Use Jan Karel's solution listed below or create your own wrapper for the .net version.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about 64bit Office, rather than just 64bit Windows, then I suggest you have a look at Jan Karel's replacement Treeview here: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Download.asp