# What is the best way to arrange treeview child node values in the excel worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Since the child nodes are related to the parent nodes, often times, the values that are specified for the child nodes are often aggregated (or summed) to the higher level nodes. These are often seen in applications such as in the accounting field.

For instance,

```
Repair and Maintenance
    Machinery
       Machine A
       Machine B
    Factory Repair
       Roof
       Floor
```

You'd want to sum `Machine A` + `Machine B` to get how much you spent for `Machinery` then you'd want to sum `Roof` + `Floor` to get how much you spend for `Factory Repair`.

Then to get the total amount you spend for `Repair and Maintenance`, you sum `Machinery` + `Factory Repair` or `Machine A` + `Machine B` + `Roof` + `Floor`.

However, my concern is, `Treeview1.Nodes.Item()` can only accept an `index` which is the order which the node was added in the treeview or the `key` which is a unique ID. There is nothing that references a node up one level and I am having difficulty in determining a way how to do accounting calculations and storing data into the worksheets.

An example of the treeview feature of the userform is shown below:

[image: Sample treeview]

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own wrapper class for the nodes that includes a parent node reference, as well as the node itself/its index, a collection of child nodes. Then you can iterate through the nodes once the tree is created, generating your wrapper classes, assigning the parent nodes as you go.

Now you have your own tree, that references the visual tree, containing all the information you need.

Comment: Care to illustrate it with a simple code example? I've been trying to think of a way for hours now. Just can't seem to think of something concrete

Comment: Not at my computer at the moment, sorry, but I suspect you might get some good ideas from ... http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4552.

Comment: Also, you might, if you can use external components, be able to use something straight out the box ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384557/alternative-to-treeview-in-vba-excel-2016-64bit

Comment: I don't know what the first link you sent is about. Is this VBA for excel related?